# Android Studio can't resolve androix.ui dependency although repository `google()` has been added

Tags: kotlin, gradle, androidx

I am kind of frustated. I want to use the `androidx.ui` dependency but gradle denies to download it.

Here is my build.gradle.kts file:

```kotlin
import org.jetbrains.compose.compose

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.4.0"
    id("org.jetbrains.compose") version "0.1.0-m1-build62"
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { setUrl("https://maven.google.com") }
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { setUrl("https://maven.google.com") }
        maven("https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/compose/dev")
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(compose.desktop.currentOs)
    implementation("androidx.ui:ui-tooling:1.0.0-alpha07")
}

compose.desktop {
    application {
        mainClass = "MainKt"
    }
}
```

Error:

> Could not resolve androidx.ui:ui-tooling:1.0.0-alpha07.
>
> Possible solution:
>
> - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html